# org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for collection using @JoinTable

Tags: hibernate, join

I have the following (simplified) situation:

Fields for TABLE A:

- ID
- COMMONID

Fields for TABLE AB:

- AID
- BID
  COMMONID

Fields for TABLE B:

- ID
- COMMONID

and want to map it with entities using a OneToMany like this (in the master class mapped on table A):

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "AB", 
joinColumns= {
    @JoinColumn(name = "AID", referencedColumnName="ID"), 
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMMONID", referencedColumnName="COMMONID")},
inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "BID", referencedColumnName="ID"), 
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMMONID", referencedColumnName="COMMONID")})
private Set<MyClassForB> list= new HashSet<MyClassForB>();
```

Building the session, I obtain the following error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for collection using @JoinTable list column: COMMONID
```

What am I doing wrong? Consider that I'm new to Hibernate.

Comment: Apparently you are using `COMMONID` in another different mapping.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find the solution please ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add insertable, and updateable like this

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "AB", 
joinColumns= {
    @JoinColumn(name = "AID", referencedColumnName="ID", insertable = false, updatable = false), 
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMMONID", referencedColumnName="COMMONID", insertable = false, updatable = false)},
inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "BID", referencedColumnName="ID", insertable = false, updatable = false), 
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMMONID", referencedColumnName="COMMONID", insertable = false, updatable = false)})
private Set<MyClassForB> list= new HashSet<MyClassForB>();
```

But I'm not sure whether you will able to update this set, my use case was read only.

Answer (score 0):

[image: ER Diagram of what you]
Assuming you allow your JPA provider (e.g. Hibernate) create the tables...try this

```
Class A{
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
    name = "AB", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_Id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "B_Id")
    )
     private Set<B> blist= new HashSet<B>();
}

Class B{
    
     @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "A_Id")
    private Set<A> blist= new HashSet<A>();
}
```